# (Woocommerce) Is it possible to hide a attribute dropdown on the product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter, attributes, product-variations

I'm having a little difficulty with WooCommerce. I'm currently developing a webshop, containing products with a lot of variations. For example:

Product 1

- Green 10 x 10 cm
- Green 10 x 15 cm
- Yellow 10 x 10 cm
- Yellow 10 x 15 cm
- Lime 10 x 10 cm
- Lime 10 x 15 cm
- etc.

Product 2

- Green 10 cm
- Green 20 cm
- Blue 10 cm
- Gray 10 cm
- Gray 20 cm
- etc.

Every product has two variations: Colour & Size. Because there are a lot of variations for each product, I'm using a plugin which displays all the variations as actual products in my shop. So when I'm filtering by attribute (for example Green), the results page only shows me green products.

But now the client would like to filter on parent attributes:

**Green hues**

- Green
- Lime
- Jade
- etc.

So I added a third attribute (Hue), so visitors can filter on that attribute. Unfortunately, this also adds a third dropdown to the product page, which isn't necessary.

Is it possible to hide and disable the Hue attribute on the product page? A way that visitors can select a color and a size, the huge dropdown has to be gone. Right now you can't add a product to your cart, before selecting a hue. I would like to remove this option. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use the hues for product filtering purposes you could create them as `Tags` instead of attributes.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't create tags for product variations, only for the main product...